# What is so special about Guinness DRAUGHT?

Tags: taste, specialty-beers, draught

I haven't heard a lot about the DRAUGHT (Guinness) in terms of its taste. But my brother insists to say that DRAUGHT is the queen of the Guinness.

But I found nothing special, indeed, I find it rather too watered down.

It is worth the hype or just a fad?

Comment: Bottled Extra Stout for me...

Comment: It has one of the biggest marketing budgets in the industry. I don't know of any beer enthusiasts who would drink it though. The bottled stuff around 7%, on the other hand, is really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beer called Guinness draft in Ireland would be called Guinness On Tap in locations such as New York.

The reason for the emphasis on draft versus in bottle is quality and taste. 
In my experience over recent decades, people pay extra for the most popular bottled beers in the US and in my opinion this is because of the guaranteed quality of bottled. Depending on the bar, the draft (tap) beer can vary from OK to well, stale, or watery, or even unhealthy in some disreputable cases. 
The bottle is much more tamper-proof.  So for this reason people will pay a couple of dollars more per drink for the same volume, of the same brand.
Having said that, your large volume commercial US (and European) beers are mostly lagers, pilsners and the like.  For these kinds of beer, the difference between bottled and high quality draft in a good bar, is small.

But Guinness stout is a very specific kind of brew.  As a variant of porter, it provides a very different experience from the bottle versus on draft.
It is very rare to see anyone in Ireland drink bottled Guinness (or any other brand of stout) in their local pub. Compared to draft, the bottled tastes bitter, is gassy and does not keep the creamy head to anything like the same extent as well served draft. In contrast, a good pint of draft stout is creamy, the maltiness well balanced with hops.  Try a taste comparison and you will see for yourself.

But have it in a reputable pub in Ireland.  There the supply chain is quality assured and the bartender is well drilled in the pour, which is also unique to draft stout.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that, at least to my knowledge, only the draught variant is made using *nitrogen* besides the usual CO2, whereas the bottled only uses CO2. This vastly changes the taste of the beer as well. If anything, you should only buy *canned draught*, which is the closest to a freshly tapped one.

Comment: Guinness Extra Stout is a different recipe than Guinness Draft, and I have never seen it on tap anywhere (including Ireland). That accounts for the difference in flavor: GES is higher original gravity and uses more hops to balance the additional malt. If you want to compare bottled Guinness vs Guinness on tap, compare it with the Guinness Draught bottles or cans, both of which contain a widget. This is essentially the same recipe as the Guinness served on tap.

Comment: Also, no matter how poorly it is handled, beer cannot be made "unhealthy". Its pH is too low to support the growth of pathogens. Wort-spoiling bacteria and wild yeasts/mold will grow in it, but they will only spoil the flavor, not make you sick.

Comment: @jalynn2 The pipes may have not been cleaned in years... or worse have been "cleaned" with something random and then not flushed. What's in the keg might be clean, but what gets into the glass could easily be "unhealthy" depending on the bar.

Answer (score 5):

Guinness Draft is an Irish Dry Stout, a session beer, with alcohol by volume at 4.2%. It is intended that you can sit and drink several pints without becoming overly intoxicated. Compare that with Bud Light, which is 4.3%. Guinness has much more flavor than Bud Light, or any other similar American Light Lager beers.

If you compare it with Guinness Extra Stout (5.6% abv) or Guinness Foreign Extra Stout (7.5% abv) or any Russian Imperial Stout like Victory Storm King (9.1%) or Stone RIS (10.6% abv), then, yes, it will taste "watered down" by comparison. But you would be comparing apples with watermelons.

Comment: I agree with this answer, pretty good stuff.

Comment: Draught = Apples. I will say this to my brother! :P

Comment: bud light is not beer and should not be in any discussion about beer.

Comment: https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2012/11/light-beer-you-dont-have-to-like-it-but-respect-it/264392/